# I need to reload/refresh page from functions.php in child theme?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, hook-woocommerce

Does anyone know how what I need to add my script below to reload.refresh my cart page (https://mysite.com.au/cart/)?

```
//Calculate shipping after item qty has changed in cart
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_refresh_update_qty');

function cart_refresh_update_qty() {
    if (is_cart()) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
    $(document.body).on('click', 'input[name="update_cart"]', function(){
        //alert('Cart Qty Changed, Shipping total will be updated - Update Button.');
        jQuery("[name='calc_shipping']").trigger("click");
    });
    });
    </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
    $(".remove").on('click', function(){
        //alert('Cart Qty Changed, Shipping total will be updated - Remove x.');
        jQuery("[name='calc_shipping']").trigger("click");
    });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to refresh the page to update data? Have you had a look at ajax in WP? https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you feedback. The data is updated, just need to reload the page to view the correct data.